# How to do a "git bundle create --all" in JGit?

Tags: git, jgit, git-bundle

Is it possible to bundle a repository using JGit?

I'm trying to do the equivalent of this git command:

```
git --git-dir=path/to/my/local/repo bundle create path/to/backup.bundle --all
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](https://download.eclipse.org/jgit/site/5.8.1.202007141445-r/apidocs/index.html), I'd say [yes](https://download.eclipse.org/jgit/site/5.8.1.202007141445-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/transport/BundleWriter.html):

> ```java
> public class BundleWriter
> extends Object
> ```
>
> Creates a Git bundle file, for sneaker-net transport to another system.

Here's an (untested) example:

```java
Repository repo = new FileRepositoryBuilder()
    .setGitDir(new File("path/to/my/local/repo/.git"))
    .build();
BundleWriter bundle = new BundleWriter(repo);

for (Ref ref : repo.getRefDatabase().getRefs()) {
    bundle.include(ref);
}

bundle.writeBundle(
    new NullProgressMonitor(),
    new FileOutputStream("path/to/backup.bundle"));
```

Comment: Works like a charm for me, thanks. The only problem I encountered is that `NullProgressMonitor()` is not available for my specific API version (5.8.1.202007141445-r). I used `new EmptyProgressMonitor() {}` instead